# Make new tab acting like static one

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, tabs

I have an question about jQuery - I'm working on big system's menu simulation, so others can play with that and decide, how it should be better organized - usability and user experience stuff.

All menu items are separated between tabs and are draggable. Also they can be dragged into other tab using jquery ui #connect-lists-through-tabs. I want to add possibility to create new tab, which is possible with same jquery ui. But, doesn't matter, what I append into new tab, it doesn't share other tab features.

Here is the addTab function:

```
function addTab() {
    var label = tabTitle.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter, id = "tabs-"
            + tabCounter, li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g,
            "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, label));
    tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
    tabs
            .append("<div id='" + id + "'>"
                    + "<ul id='sortable1' class='connectedSortable ui-helper-reset'><li class='ui-state-default'>Im an menu item</li><div class='dragme'>...</div></ul>"
                    + "</div>");
    tabs.tabs("refresh");
    tabCounter++;
}
```

I create new tab with div in it which contains `<ul>` class, which must be sortable and so on, but it is not.

Adding new `<li>` items by code into static tabs working fine.

May be someone have any idea, how can I solve this problem?
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to enable the drag and drop function in jquery you need to initialise it. what you maybe do after loading the page.

so when you add a tab into your menu you need also initialise the drag and drop feature for this new element.

just run your drag and drop function from the beginning again and it should work.

or you use this addtab function:

```
function addTab() {
var label = tabTitle.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter, id = "tabs-"
        + tabCounter, li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g,
        "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, label));
tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
tabs
        .append("<div id='" + id + "'>"
                + "<ul id='sortable1' class='connectedSortable ui-helper-reset'><li class='ui-state-default'>Im an menu item</li><div class='dragme'>...</div></ul>"
                + "</div>");
tabs.tabs("refresh");

$('#' + id).draggable();
tabCounter++;
```

}

the specified config for draggable can you find [here](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)